# R shiny brush can not be removed by any means. Can anyone help me?

Tags: r, shiny, brush

in an R shiny app, I am trying to implement a zoom functionality and found that SOME brush rectangles can not be removed from the plots by any means I found.
[Remaining brush rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYrGc.png)

I tried several programming solutions, including:

- resetOnNew = T
- session$resetBrush(input$brush_zoom)
- runjs("document.getElementById('brush_zoom').remove()")  with the shinyjs library

Any of these seem to work - most of the time, but not always.
Now, I found that the non-deletable rectangles seem to be from brush strokes, where I pulled a rectangle open and made it a bit smaller again before releasing the mouse. If I pull the rectangle open and release the mouse, they are reset.

Does anyone else have this problem and hopefully a solution?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tried this with several apps. It is not a problem produced by my plot generating code.